# Iterate over columns in python dataframe to do calculations and insert new columns between existing columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python and programming in general and can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have a dataframe imported from an excel sheet with 15 rows of species and their number and 3 columns which are locations where they are found. That is a species by station matrix:

```
              A1    A2    A3
Species 1   1259   600   151
Species 2    912  1820   899
Species 3   1288  1491   631
Species 4     36   609  1946
Species 5   1639   819  1864
Species 6   1989   748   843
Species 7    688   271  1206
Species 8   1031   341   756
Species 9   1517  1164   138
Species 10  1290   669   811
Species 11    16   409  1686
Species 12   329   521   954
Species 13  1782   958  1727
Species 14   464  1804  1105
Species 15  1002  1483   109
```

I want to calculate for each column the top-10 species (index), their value, percentage of total in column, cumulative percentage and insert the new columns after each exististing column and return in one dataframe.

This is the result I'm looking for (example with two first columns):

```
     Species    A1  pct  cum_pct     Species    A2  pct  cum_pct   
0   Species 6  1989   13       13   Species 2  1820   13       13  
1  Species 13  1782   11       24  Species 14  1804   13       26   
2   Species 5  1639   10       35   Species 3  1491   10       37   
3   Species 9  1517    9       45  Species 15  1483   10       48  
4  Species 10  1290    8       53   Species 9  1164    8       56   
5   Species 3  1288    8       62  Species 13   958    6       63    
6   Species 1  1259    8       70   Species 5   819    5       69  
7   Species 8  1031    6       77   Species 6   748    5       75    
8  Species 15  1002    6       83  Species 10   669    4       79   
9   Species 2   912    5       89   Species 4   609    4       84
```

I have managed to do this by calculating each column and make new data frames and using concat to merge the data frames together in the end using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"") #local excel file

#extract first column and remove others
df = df.drop(df.columns[1:], axis=1) 

# create column which has percentage for each element: divide value by total sum
df["pct"] = 100*(df.iloc[:, 0] /df.iloc[:, 0].sum())

#sort by value in Column 1 (0) return only top n (10) values
df = df.sort_values(by=df.columns[0], ascending=False).head(10)

# Create column with cumulative sum
df["cum_pct"] = df.pct.cumsum()

#make index as column and change name to Species
df = df.reset_index()

df = df.rename(index=str, columns={"index": "Species"})


# For column 2
df1 = pd.read_excel(r"") #local excel file

df1 = df1.drop(df1.columns[2:], axis=1) 
df1 = df1.drop(df1.columns[0], axis=1) 

# create column which has percentage for each element: divide value by total sum
df1["pct"] = 100*(df1.iloc[:, 0] /df1.iloc[:, 0].sum())


#sort by value in Column 1 (0) return only top n (10) values
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=df1.columns[0], ascending=False).head(10)

# Create column with cumulative sum
df1["cum_pct"] = df1.pct.cumsum()

# set index as first column
df1 = df1.reset_index()

df1 = df1.rename(index=str, columns={"index": "Species"})


# concatenate all dataframes
result = pd.concat([df, df1,], axis=1, join_axes=[df.index])

#convert numbers to int, exception = ignore
result = result.astype(int, errors="ignore")

print(result)
```

This code works, but my datasets are much larger with often more then 50 columns so I'm wondering if it possible to an iteration for each column that results in the same dataframe as shown above. Sorry for the long read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `for` loop, [`Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with `lambda` functions to calculate `pct` and `cum_pct` and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine for final output frame:

```
frames = []
for col in df:
    frames.append(df[col].nlargest(10).to_frame()
                  .assign(pct=lambda x: x[col] / df[col].sum(),
                          cum_pct=lambda x: x['pct'].cumsum())
                  .rename_axis('Species').reset_index())


df_new = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

[out]

```
      Species    A1       pct   cum_pct     Species    A2       pct   cum_pct  \
0   Species 6  1989  0.130495  0.130495   Species 2  1820  0.132779  0.132779   
1  Species 13  1782  0.116914  0.247408  Species 14  1804  0.131612  0.264390   
2   Species 5  1639  0.107532  0.354940   Species 3  1491  0.108777  0.373167   
3   Species 9  1517  0.099528  0.454468  Species 15  1483  0.108193  0.481360   
4  Species 10  1290  0.084635  0.539102   Species 9  1164  0.084920  0.566280   
5   Species 3  1288  0.084503  0.623606  Species 13   958  0.069891  0.636171   
6   Species 1  1259  0.082601  0.706207   Species 5   819  0.059750  0.695922   
7   Species 8  1031  0.067642  0.773849   Species 6   748  0.054571  0.750492   
8  Species 15  1002  0.065739  0.839588  Species 10   669  0.048807  0.799300   
9   Species 2   912  0.059835  0.899423   Species 4   609  0.044430  0.843729   

      Species    A3       pct   cum_pct  
0   Species 4  1946  0.131256  0.131256  
1   Species 5  1864  0.125725  0.256981  
2  Species 13  1727  0.116485  0.373466  
3  Species 11  1686  0.113719  0.487185  
4   Species 7  1206  0.081344  0.568528  
5  Species 14  1105  0.074531  0.643059  
6  Species 12   954  0.064346  0.707406  
7   Species 2   899  0.060637  0.768043  
8   Species 6   843  0.056860  0.824902  
9  Species 10   811  0.054701  0.879603
```

---

If it's necessary to format the calculated fields `pct` and `cum_pct` as `int`, then instead use:

```
frames = []
for col in df:
    frames.append(df[col].nlargest(10).to_frame()
                  .assign(pct=lambda x: x[col] / df[col].sum(),
                          cum_pct=lambda x: x['pct'].cumsum())
                  .assign(pct=lambda x: x['pct'].mul(100).astype(int),
                          cum_pct=lambda x: x['cum_pct'].mul(100).astype(int))
                  .rename_axis('Species').reset_index())


df_new = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

[out]

```
     Species    A1  pct  cum_pct     Species    A2  pct  cum_pct     Species  \
0   Species 6  1989   13       13   Species 2  1820   13       13   Species 4   
1  Species 13  1782   11       24  Species 14  1804   13       26   Species 5   
2   Species 5  1639   10       35   Species 3  1491   10       37  Species 13   
3   Species 9  1517    9       45  Species 15  1483   10       48  Species 11   
4  Species 10  1290    8       53   Species 9  1164    8       56   Species 7   
5   Species 3  1288    8       62  Species 13   958    6       63  Species 14   
6   Species 1  1259    8       70   Species 5   819    5       69  Species 12   
7   Species 8  1031    6       77   Species 6   748    5       75   Species 2   
8  Species 15  1002    6       83  Species 10   669    4       79   Species 6   
9   Species 2   912    5       89   Species 4   609    4       84  Species 10   

     A3  pct  cum_pct  
0  1946   13       13  
1  1864   12       25  
2  1727   11       37  
3  1686   11       48  
4  1206    8       56  
5  1105    7       64  
6   954    6       70  
7   899    6       76  
8   843    5       82  
9   811    5       87
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly. Amazing that the code can be so compact. I got a pct key-error running your script, but changed it slightly so it worked. I changed the line "cum_pct=lambda x: x['pct'].cumsum())" to ".assign(cum_pct=lambda x: x['pct'].cumsum())"